# Connecting to Bonobo Git Server using .NET to retrieve comments on repos

Tags: c#, git, bonobo

Anyone have any idea where to start? we have http://git.mydomain.com running and I can use my login/pass to see list of repos/projects.

I would like to be able to connect to the git server using c# in order to get list of projects and all the commit comments through some sort of API.

I have the url to the git server, my username/pass for credentials, that is all I have and that it is running on Bonobo Git Server.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Git itself which has this overview of multiple projects/repositories, you would need Bonobo to provide some kind of API, which it doesn't.